# Function defined in my user's .bashrc causes an error when I sudo su

Tags: bash, python, sudo, bashrc

I have a function defined in my user's .bashrc file that displays my current git branch name at my command prompt:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
PS1="\\[$(tput setaf 7)\\]\\w \$(parse_git_branch)> \\[$(tput sgr0)\\]"
```

When I sudo to su, it looks like my PS1 is carried over, and after every command I get the error `bash: parse_git_branch: command not found`.

What can I change so that when I sudo to another user, its PS1 is used and not that of my user?

Edit: It seems like this only happens after I use source a Python virtualenv. If I sudo su before I source the virtualenv, this error does not occur.

Comment: maybe moving this functuon form bashrc to .profile could solve the problem - try it out.

Comment: @mnmnc `.profile` is only read by login shells.

Comment: What error are you getting? It seems to cause no problems on my system. `sudo su` has the normal PS1.

Comment: @terdon I'm not getting any errors other than "command not found" when I sudo su.

Comment: Actually it seems like this only happens after I use source a Python virtualenv. If I sudo su before I source the virtualenv, this error does not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ever `expor PS1` somewhere (e.g. in your *Python virtualenv*)? I always have this line in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
export -n PS1 # unexport PS1 so sub-processes will not inherit it
```

So try `export -n PS1` before you `sudo`.

Answer (score 7):

`PS1` is not being reset by `sudo`, it's kept by default. Functions are part of the bash environment, but are not preserved by `sudo`. You can do any of several things:

- instead use `sudo su -` so you get a login shell, that will reset `PS1`
- set `env_reset` to "clean up" the environment, possibly with `env_keep`
- set `SUDO_PS1` and sudo will place that value in `PS1`
- use `sudo -i` which is similar to `su -` (you'll need to add your shell to the `sudoers` file)
- check the variable `SUDO_COMMAND` in your `.bashrc` and reset `PS1`

The list of variables that `sudo` keeps (may vary by version, check `env.c` in the source) includes:

```
DISPLAY COLORS LS_COLORS HOSTNAME PS1 PS2 TZ
```

This is a hardcoded list, it's not the same thing as `env_keep` (i.e. "`env_keep -=`" won't change it).

Run `sudo -V` as root for a full list of variables preserved or removed (for `sudo` version >= v1.7).

One final suggestion, you could make your `PS1` more robust by checking if the function exists:

```
PS1="\\[$(tput setaf 7)\\]\\w \$(type -t parse_git_branch >/dev/null && parse_git_branch)> \\[$(tput sgr0)\\]"
```

Comment: Usually an env var would not be passed to the child processes unless the var is exported. So if `PS1` is not exported `sudo` will not see or keep it.

Comment: Yes you're perfectly correct, usually it's wanted (so you don't need to fix it in subshells), but you can also `export -n PS1` so that it's *not* exported.